# How to set a trigger in Parsley for all input fields via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

Using ParsleyJs, I'd like to set the trigger for each input field to `focusout`.

I'm able to set it through data attributes in the html, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="my-input
       data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
       required>
```

To do the same in Javascript I tried this:

```
const formInstance = $('#myForm').parsley();
const inputs = $('input').parsley();

for (let input of inputs) {
  input.options.trigger = 'focusout';
}
```

But it's not adding the trigger.

Comment: [The Parsley.js documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html) quite clearly shows that you set options via `$("selector for the form").parsley(options);`. So presumably, `$("selector for the form containing these inputs").parsley({trigger: "focusout"})` (though I certainly wouldn't turn off `input`, so perhaps `"focusout input"`). Have you tried that?

Comment: That's not a normal jQuery object, it's a parsley instance. And the Parsley documentations shows this example:`var field = $('input').parsley();console.log(field.options.maxlength); // Shows that maxlength is 42`

Comment: I realized that and edited the comment almost immediately. Again: Did you try changing the options as per the documentation? *(Note: Comments on votes are never useful.)*

Answer (score 0):

You're right, according to their documentation, it seems like your code should be working.

For now, you can pass the options when you call `parsley()`.

```
const options = {
    trigger: 'focusout'
};

const inputs = $('input').parsley(options);
```

And remove the loop.

Comment: It took me a while, but I found out the issue. I wrote the form adding the `data-form-validate` attribute. On the documentation there's a warning saying `Do not add data-parsley-validate to your forms ... Once a form or field instance is bound by Parsley, doing $('#form').parsley(options); will update the existing options but not replace them. ` Not sure what they mean by "update the existing options", then, but removing the attribute fixed the issue